# incomplete line chart with mpandroid

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I wanna draw a line chart with mpAndroid
I've two double arrayLists, Pn_points and Mn_points
these data are added to yVals but when I run the program the chart is drawn incompletely!

favorite chart
[image]

final chart (incomplete!)
[image]

```
lineChart=(LineChart) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        int size=Pn_points.size();
        ArrayList<Entry> yVals = new ArrayList<Entry>();
         TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            double y2=Math.round(Pn_points.get(i)/1000*100.0)/100.0;
            double x2=Math.round(Mn_points.get(i)/100000*100.0)/100.0;
            float y=(float)y2 ;
            float x=(float)x2 ;
            yVals.add(new Entry(x,y));
        }
           LineDataSet sety=new LineDataSet(yVals,"yData");
           LineData data=new LineData(sety);
           lineChart.setData(data);
           lineChart.animateX(3000);
           lineChart.setDragEnabled(true);
           lineChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that in a line chart (that represents the graph of a function), there can't exist two y values for one x value. Your graph can't change its direction.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by a combined chart. You have to create two datasets and generate two lines. I think it can be done in that way only. So use combined chart of mpAndroidChart. Let me know for further assistance.